# Artifacts in DensityPlot (Wolfram Mathematica)

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica, density-plot

I am trying to visualize the result of numerical integration in Wolfram Mathematica using DensityPlot. But dark artifacts appear inside the circle on the graph, this is incorrect. How to fix this?

```
f[u_, v_]:=(1/1.2)*(1/(3.14159*0.02^2)*E^(-((x-u)^2+(y-v)^2)/0.02^2)+0.2/(3.14159*2^2)*E^(-((x-u)^2+(y-v)^2)/2^2));
i[x_, y_]:=NIntegrate[f[u, v],{u, v} \[Element] Disk[{0,0},2.5],  AccuracyGoal -> 30];
DensityPlot[i[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},ColorFunction->"SunsetColors",PlotPoints -> 20, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Link to the image: https://postimg.cc/47MJTYj7

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is not an artifact, or is it. First I'd like to point out that `f` is a function of `u`, `v`, `x` and `y`. So the way it is programmed is not very clean. Now to the main problem. There are two Gaussian peaks. One is very broad, the other very sharp. In many cases the numerical integral just does not get points near the sharp peak, therefore not detecting it. As the rest is smooth and easy, no subset is generated and the integral is just missing this contribution. Luckily, there is an option specifically for this. `MinRecursion: NIntegrate may miss sharp peaks of integrands:...`. So this works

```
g[x_, y_, s_] := Exp[ -( x^2 + y^2 ) / s^2] / (s^2 Pi)
f[x_, y_, u_, v_] := g[ x - u, y - v, 0.02 ] / 1.2 + 0.2 g[ x - u, y - v, 2 ]  
i[x_, y_] := NIntegrate[ f[x, y, u, v], {u, v} \[Element] Disk[{0, 0}, 2.5], MinRecursion -> 5]

nn = 30;
t = Table[i[x, y], {x, -3, 3, 6/nn}, {y, -3, 3, 6/nn}];
ListDensityPlot[t, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: mysolution]

Takes quite some time, though. Probably, it would be better to split this up in two integrals and invest some thought on the integration boundaries.